# Kubernetes Custom Resource Status with helm-based operator using operator-sdk

Tags: kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-operator, kubernetes-custom-resources, operator-sdk

I have created a Helm Based Operator Of Freeradius Server.

I would like for each Free Radius Instance to include at the Custom Resource Status the Nodeport Service Resource IP and Port number.

Is there any way to do it by only using Helm-Based Operators ?

Comment: Do you want to expose pod information to running containers ? If yes, you can use Downward API to retrieve "status.podIP" etc. Checkout https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/downward-api-volume-expose-pod-information/